# GFI safety on electrical outlet

Tags: electrical

I have a Ground Fault outlet in my bathroom and I replaced it  thinking it was bad.  The new will not reset unless I disconnect the load line. Can I safely use the outlet without hooking the load wires to the outlet?  I know my outlets outside will not work as they are connected to the Ground Fault outlet.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is safe. NO, it is not what you should do.

The proper fix for this is to find out why the GFI is tripping. It is doing it's job and you need to find out why.

Comment: Doesn't NEC 210.11(C)(3) prohibit 'outside' receptacles from being powered off the bath circuit?

Comment: @Mazura, yes, now, but it was common in the 60's and 70's.

Comment: My house was built in 1979/1980 and had that problem, stuff was always tripping. A rewire a few years ago split each bathroom, kitchen, and outside on their own circuit. I think we tripped a breaker once since then. It was a very good use of time and resources to fix the situation.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to run with the outside outlet disconnected.  Just cap the wires so they don't become a potential short hazard.

But that said, my personal preference is to put a dedicated GFI outlet in each location.  Get an outdoor rated GFI outlet for outside and instead of wiring it to the load of the bathrooms GFI, move it to the same terminals as line (if the outlet is rated for two wires on the terminal) or wire caps the hots together with a pigtail (same for neutrals) and connect the bathroom GFI to the pigtail.

Comment: You should also attempt to determine why the outside outlets keep tripping your GFI. It's possible there's a faulty connection or a ground leak somewhere.

Comment: Outside outlet is most likely corroded and causing a small amount of electricity to leak to the ground.

Comment: A GFCI in each location!? You must be rich.

Comment: You can look at it as a 30 dollar convenience/time saver.  Is the tool I'm using outside not working or is the GFCI tripped?  Let me go clean myself up before I go inside (don't want the wife killing me) to check the status of the circuit.  Same thing for my bath rooms, I have one in each since they are on different floors.

Comment: @Tester101, not at all. I had the same situation at my own home when I bought it. One GFI breaker controlled two bathrooms and two outside receptacles. Incredibly inconvenient so I put 4 GFI's in place of the receptacles and a regular breaker.

Comment: @diceless, sorry, but I wholly disagree with your opening statement. Not that it's not safe, but it is not at all correct to suggest simply losing the outside receptacles. Things like that cause folks to use long extension cords many times plugged into non-GFI protected receptacles.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey I'm just saying, from a cost perspective it makes sense to protect as much as you can from a single device. Convince isn't usually top priority if your broke, or just cheap.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey valid point.

Comment: @Tester101, if you're broke you shouldn't be building a home or doing renovations either. :)

Comment: @SpeedyPetey Even if you're broke, things break and need to be repaired.